# Создается пустой элемент | Добавление элементов в LinearLayout

Tags: android, android-linearlayout

Есть шаблон элемента:

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
    android:background="@color/background_pin_themplate"
    android:padding="15dp">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/book_card_image"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="300dp"
        android:background="@color/design_default_color_secondary"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/book_card_text"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:text="@string/example_title"
        android:textColor="@color/colorHeader"
        android:textSize="30sp"
        app:fontFamily="@font/roboto_medium"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/book_card_image" />
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Есть код:

```
public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        HomeViewModel homeViewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(this).get(HomeViewModel.class);
        root = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home, container, false);

        LinearLayout layout = root.findViewById(R.id.recommended);

        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++){
            View view  = inflater.inflate(R.layout.card_book_home, container, false);
            TextView title = view.findViewById(R.id.book_card_text);
            ImageView image = view.findViewById(R.id.book_card_image);
            title.setText("Книга " + i);
            image.setBackgroundResource(R.color.colorHeader);

            Log.i("<<<<<<<<<<< I", String.valueOf(title.getText()));

            layout.addView(view);
        }

        return root;
    }
```

Код должен просто добавлять элементы в layout. И это происходит! Но, почему-то текст и изображение просто пропадают! Что делать?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Нашел ответ. Как оказалось, я накосячил с размерами элементов. Сам шаблон у меня растягивался по максимуму, а LinearLayout был высотой всего 215dp. Поэтому вместо текста мне показывало пустое изображение.